# Is it possible to configure R graphics event handling on OSX with RStudio?

Tags: r, macos, x11

I am using the kml package in R and in order to choose a partition, I need to use a function that relies on an interactive graphics environment.

Trying to run the `choice` function, but I get this error:

```
Error in setGraphicsEventEnv(which, as.environment(list(...))) : 
  this graphics device does not support event handling
```

Googling around has not yielded any leads.

Comment: Note that this is not an OSX specific issue. Same happens on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [this page](http://answer.techwikihow.com/9065/setgraphicseventenv-supported-under-linux.html) that suggested doing `X11(type="Xlib")`, which seems to have done the trick.